# What is the domain, range, and give some contour maps of $\max(|x|,y^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

What is the domain, range, and give some contour maps of $\max(|x|,y^2)$.

I even don't know how to examine this function, what is the max function exactly?

Comment: $\max{(a,b)}$ gives the larger of $a$ and $b$, i.e. $a$ if $a>b$, $b$ if $b\geq a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For domain:
Let $f(x,y) = \max(|x|, y^2)$. How many input does the function take in? Can $x$ and $y$ be any real numbers? If you can answer these questions, you should know the domain.

For the range: Is it possible for the function to take negative value? Can it take any nonnegative value?

For the contour map, note that $f(x,y)=f(-x,y)=f(x,-y)=f(-x,-y)$, we can focus on the first quadrant and obtain the rest by symmetry.

From now on, I will assume $x \geq 0, y \geq 0$.

Consider $$\max(|x|, y^2) =\max(x,y^2)= k$$

where $k \geq 0$.

If $y^2 \geq x$, $y =  \sqrt{k}$

If $y^2 < x$, $x= k$.

By symmetry, for a given value of $k \geq 0$. $(x,y)$ which satisfy the condition that $f(x,y)=k$ will form a rectangle using the lines $x=k$, $x=-k$, $y=\sqrt{k}$ and $y = -\sqrt{k}$

Comment: I assume, that $x$ and $y$ can be any real numbers, am I right? So will be the domain the whole real line?

Comment: since there are two entries, it should be $\mathbb{R}^2$. An example of an element of $\mathbb{R}$ is $0$. An example of en element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $(0,0)$, our function takes in two real numbers.